# View is not getting rendered in Zend Framework 3

Tags: php, model-view-controller, view, zend-framework3

We have recently migrated one of our application to Zend Framework 3 (ZF3) from Zend Framework 1.x.
The migrated application is working fine in my local. When we deployed the changes to the TEST environment, with upgraded ZF3, the view is not getting rendered!

HomeController - Index Action

```
class HomeController extends AbstractActionController {

    /**
     *
     * Logger Instance
     * @var Logger
     */
    private $_logger;
    private $serviceManager;
    private $viewModel;

    public function __construct(ServiceManager $serviceManager) {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
        $this->serviceManager = $serviceManager;
        $this->_logger = new Logger(str_replace('_', '.', __CLASS__));
        $this->viewModel = new ViewModel();
        
        $shutdownParam = null;
        register_shutdown_function(array(Utils::getInstance(), 'shutdownHandler'), $shutdownParam);
    }

    public function indexAction() {
        
        //Set the page title
        $this->viewModel->setVariable('pageTitle', Utils::getInstance()->getMessages("title", 'msg_title_home', false));

        $requestParams = array_merge($this->params()->fromPost(), $this->params()->fromQuery());
        //$this->_logger->debug(print_r($requestParams, true));
        try {
            $userSettings = new UserSettings();
            $this->viewModel->setVariable('settingsForPage', $userSettings->getSettingsForPage('xxx'));
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->_logger->error("Error Loading settings: $e");
            $this->viewModel->setVariable('settingsForPage', "{}");
        }

        $this->viewModel->showHeader = (array_key_exists('header', $requestParams) && $requestParams['header'] == '0') ? false : true;
        $this->viewModel->showFooter = (array_key_exists('footer', $requestParams) && $requestParams['footer'] == '0') ? 'false' : 'true';
        return $this->viewModel;
    }
```

CommonControllerFactory Code

```
namespace Application\Controller\Factory;

use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface;
use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;

class CommonControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = NULL)
    {
        $serviceManager = $container->get('ServiceManager');
        return new $requestedName($serviceManager);
    }
    
}
```

view/home/index.phtml

```
<?php include(APPLICATION_PATH.'/Application/view/application/common/header.inc'); ?>
<body ondragstart="return false">
    
<?php include(APPLICATION_PATH.'/Application/view/application/common/footer.inc'); ?>

<!-- page specific -->
</body>
</html>
```

layout.phtml

```
<?= $this->content ?>
```

module.config.php

```
    'view_manager' => [
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => [
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
            'application/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/index/index.phtml',
            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
            'application/home/index'    => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/home/index.phtml',
        ],
        'template_path_stack' => [
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ],
    ],
```

There are some warnings showing from library side:
[image]

From the debugging, understood that the content of the view (index.phtml) is not injected into the $content variable of the layout. Not sure why!

Comment: Are you sure you copied **all** configuration files to your test environment? Looks like something is missing..

Comment: Hi @Ermenegildo, Actually I have generated the build (.tar.gz file) and deployed in TEST environment. To ensure no files missed, I have setup installed Zend Framework 3 using composer in another directory path in the TEST environment, but there also I am facing the same issue